# Get current user id

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, functions, user-meta

I need to print the user's id into this array but it doesn't seem to be working. I have tried all sorts of things from $user->ID to $user_id to no avail. I am trying to get the value from my functions.php
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here what's in my php function:

```
$user_page = get_queried_object();
$user_id = $user_page->data->ID;
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'listings',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'stm_car_user',
                'value' => $user_id
            )
        )
    );

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

I'm sorry if my question is a little vague, here is what I am trying to achieve I don't want to get the id of the currently logged in user, I want to get the id of the user that the information is on, I am displaying the user's posts on their profiles and I need their id's displayed dynamically for each profile, you get me? I hope this clarifies things...

Comment: I approached by get_users method. It returns user object, and it has ID property. also wp_get_current_user methods can help as well.

Comment: @idpokute I'm sorry, I'm kind of a newbie, how would you rewrite the array for the way that you're saying that it works?

Comment: Note that using `meta_query` is terribly slow/expensive, you should be better off using a taxonomy named `stm_car_user` where the term names are user IDs, it would be significantly faster

Comment: @TomJNowell How would I go about writing that please?

Comment: @MattH That would be a good question, but not something for the comments, having said that any answer would basically just be a more verbose version of my comment

Comment: When you say you're trying to get the value from your `functions.php`, can you tell us more about the context? What exactly is the current queried object? When does this run? And what does the query do once it's been created?

Comment: @TomJNowell I've edited my question so hopefully it's a little clearer what I'm trying to achieve..

Comment: @MattH thanks for the update but I don't follow, what if the main query contains posts from more than 1 person, or the user is in a category archive? I suspect this question only applies to a particular template, to particular situations, but that doesn't explain why your code is in `functions.php` and not a template such as `profile.php`

Comment: Perhaps it would help if we ignored the code and you simply described what your site currently does from a users perspective, and the difference between what it does and what it needs to do, I'm getting a strong vibe that there's a lot of assumed stuff here, and if I were your client what you said would make perfect sense, but the lack of context makes the question confusing and unclear

Comment: Ok basically it's a classified ads website and it has users which have profiles and when you visit each user's profile it has a list of their classified ads that they have uploaded to the site. I simply want to be able to switch from list to grid mode when viewing their ads. When you first visit their profile their ads show up normally but when I execute the ajax code it returns all posts on the website instead of that particular user's posts.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is literally the title with underscores instead of spaces:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/

Comment: I don't want to get the id of the currently logged in user, I want to get the id of the user that the information is on, I am displaying the user's posts on their profiles and I need their id's displayed dynamically for each profile, you get me?

Comment: Ah, that's not what your question asks, can you edit your question to remove that ambiguity? You never qualified `current`, I'd recommend instead saying the author of a post

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong it should be

```
$user_page->ID
```

Also you can check

```
get_queried_object_id()
```

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work....

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example, this is display all users in subscribers role.

```
$subscribers = get_users( [ 'role__in' => [ 'subscriber' ] ] );
// Array of WP_User objects.
foreach ( $subscribers as $user ) {
    echo '<span>' . $user->ID . '</span>';
}
```

Comment: How do I echo the $user->ID outside of the loop though? It doesn't work..

Comment: You get the all the subscribers, which is array. You can access the first user id in the array using array syntax. For instance,     $subscribers[0]->ID;

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately....

Comment: @MattH I saw the duplicated post of yours which is about ajax request and response. If I understand correctly, you are trying to make infinite scroll. If you don't have any subscriber, it won't work. Change subscriber to administrator, check whether it is working or not using var_dump. By the way what role of users do you want to pull?

Comment: I am not trying to make an infinite scroll but if you have a solution for the infinite scroll then I would greatly appreciate it and I want to get the id of all users by all roles...

Answer (score 0):

If you use an author.php file in your theme then it would automatically get the posts from that author.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates#Which_Template_File_is_Used.3F

That way you don't need to manually code your own and wp core code to link to author profiles would work without any modifications.